# What do time fields in CounterSample mean?

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

I have an instance of `PerformanceCounter`, I call `NextSample()` on it and get a `CounterSample`. In it, there are several time-related fields: CounterFrequency, SystemFrequency, CounterTimeStamp, Timestamp and TimeStamp100nSec.

The [MSDN page for CounterSample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.countersample.counterfrequency.aspx) only says "Gets the raw counter frequency" and similar unhelpful descriptions, and a sample that prints the value without explanations.

- What do these mean exactly?
- In what units are they? I tried all `DateTime.FromX()` functions, but none produces a reasonable result.

Comment: have a look at the doc of [PerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: As the question indicates, the MSDN documentation on this is useless.

Comment: You can get the UTC timestamp of the counter sample from the following expression: `DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(sample.TimeStamp100nSec)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(sample2.Timestamp - sample1.Timestamp) / sample2.SystemFrequency = elapsed seconds

(sample2.TimeStamp100nSec - sample1.TimeStamp100nSec) / 10000000 = elapsed seconds
```

I was able to reverse engineer this when I was analyzing how LOGMAN.EXE would read perf counters and store them in a SQL database. CounterSample class (from various disassemblies) wraps this C structure

[PDH_RAW_COUNTER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

In this C structure, SecondValue has either TimeStamp or TimeStamp100nSec [depending on the counter type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecountertype.aspx). By the time it gets wrapped in .NET CounterSample struct, you can get either via the properties.

Comment: this pretty much confirms my findings: http://typedescriptor.net/browse/members/335094-System.Diagnostics.CounterSampleCalculator.GetElapsedTime(CounterSample,CounterSample)